# How to set IBM Watson Speech to Text to recognize a File Immediately?

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I'm trying to recognize a file that I have (10 seconds of recording) but it appears that Watson is playing the sound on their side and calculating the speech for each second of audio (or something like that).

Is it possible to instead of that approach it immediately returns me the whole audio? Like in less than 3 seconds? (I'm asking that because right now I'm using AT&T STT service and it returns me back the audio very fast, like 3 seconds at max - and I know it uses IBM Watson...)

As recommended in their Getting Started Docs, this is my java code using IBM.Watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text SDK:

```
    log.info("Starting to recognize...");
    getToken();
    File audio = new File(recordingPath);
    RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder().contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)
            .continuous(true).interimResults(true)
            .build();
    SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(audio, options).execute();
    lastRecognitionRequest = Calendar.getInstance();

    String result = "";
    for(Transcript t : transcript.getResults()) {
        result = result.concat(t.getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript());
    }

    log.info(result);
```

Thank you,

Comment: Leo AT&T watson is different than IBM Watson or the IBM Watson Speech to Text

Comment: Thank you for the information @GermanAttanasio I did not know that. :( Maybe there's no way to do what I'm trying with IBM Watson... Well I'm trying to check with their inside community to here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/294642/how-to-set-ibm-watson-speech-to-text-to-recognize.html#answer-294855 

Nikolay Shmyrev thank you, but it's not the same case